# Trying to connect to my FTP server from my browser does a search instead of taking me to the directory. Same link works in Firefox but not on others

Tags: linux, ssh, debian, ftp, brave

I have a ftp server `ftp://192.168.1.6:2121/` which I want to connect to using my browser but instead it does a search on duckduckgo. The same link works in firefox but all the other browsers fail. I use brave and opera and both did a search using the search engine instead of actially taking me to the directory.

Am I doing it wrong or can it be a bug that I should report?

This is on brave
[image: on brave]

And this is on firefox

[image]

As you can see brave automatically tries to search it using the search engine but firefox looks up the web using the ftp.

Also tried chromium and faced the same results that I did with brave and opera.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

FTP is bring deprecated. But for now, there is still a flag to enable it.

1. On the address bar, type: `chrome://flags`.
2. Search for `#enable-ftp`.
3. Enable it, and restart the browser.

Note that the flag might be removed in future releases of the browser.

Comment: This works. Is it possible to share files over something else but in a similar fashion to that of FTP. If you have any keywords that I can research upon and find an alternative.

Comment: @decipher You can try using scp or pscp from the terminal. Or use Filezilla or others if you want a graphical interface.

Comment: It only tool two months for your answer to become out-dated. I took the liberty of [posting an updated answer](https://superuser.com/a/1667288/156554). I did not wanted to edit your answer, to change it into mine, because I expect that my answer will be similarly short-living and thus I want to keep both of them for historic reasons.

Comment: @trejder No isuue. +1 for the update on your answer. Seems for now, one needs to use old browser  versions and the like of Filezilla.

Comment: 2023, chrome 111.0: it's gone

Answer (score 2):

Most browsers are today moving away from supporting the `ftp` protocol.

This is for the same reason of security as that of the move away from the
`http` protocol to `https`.

While there exists an [ftps protocol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FTPS),
the implementations currently incorporated in most browsers do not
support it.

For example, see the Chrome/Chromium article
[Deprecate and remove support for FTP URLs](https://chromestatus.com/feature/6246151319715840):

> The current FTP implementation in Google Chrome has no support for
> encrypted connections (FTPS), nor proxies. Usage of FTP in the browser
> is sufficiently low that it is no longer viable to invest in improving
> the existing FTP client. In addition more capable FTP clients are
> available on all affected platforms.
>
> Google Chrome 72+ removed support for fetching document subresources
> over FTP and rendering of top level FTP resources. Currently
> navigating to FTP URLs result in showing a directory listing or a
> download depending on the type of resource. A bug in Google Chrome 74+
> resulted in dropping support for accessing FTP URLs over HTTP proxies.
> Proxy support for FTP was removed entirely in Google Chrome 76.
>
> Remaining capabilities of Google Chrome’s FTP implementation are
> restricted to either displaying a directory listing or downloading a
> resource over unencrypted connections. We would like to deprecate and
> remove this remaining functionality rather than maintain an insecure
> FTP implementation.

Although Firefox still supports `ftp`, I would think that it would also
adopt this policy in the future.
You might still be able to find browser extensions to support it,
but it would be better and more lasting to use a utility for accessing `ftp`.

Comment: I see. Now that I have learned of the security flaws of ftp I'd actually like to move away to some alternative. I am currently looking for one. But I shouldn't have worry about anybody who is not on my network getting access to my ftp server right?

Answer (score 2):

The `enable-ftp` flag (and thus entire FTP protocol support) has been completely disabled and descoped as of *Chrome 91* and *Edge 91*.

Right now (August 2021) you still [have a chance too access FTP addresses](https://onezeronull.com/2021/07/27/enable-ftp-support-in-chrome-edge-august-2021/) in Chrome / Edge (details below), but I expect that my answer will become outdated in next couple of months just as it took only two months for [Reddy Lutonadio's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1652303/156554) to become outdated.

To be able to access FTP sites in Chrome 92 (and newer?) or Edge 92 (and newer?) follow these steps.

1. On the Chrome's address bar type: `chrome://flags` (or `edge://flags` in Microsoft Edge)
2. Type or paste `M91` in search bar
3. Change value of *Temporarily unexpire M91 flags* flag from *Default* to *Enabled*
4. Click *Relaunch* (Chrome) / *Restart* (Edge) in the right-bottom corner
5. Type or paste `ftp` in search bar
6. Change value of *Enable support for FTP URLs* flag from *Default* to *Enabled*
7. Click *Relaunch* (Chrome) / *Restart* (Edge) in the right-bottom corner

Similarly to [Reddy Lutonadio's answer](https://superuser.com/a/1652303/156554) above, I expect the *Temporarily unexpire M91 flags* flag to be removed in future releases of both browsers, thus making FTP protocol not available in Chrome / Edge for good.

Comment: 2023, chrome 111.0: it's gone. T_T

Answer (score 2):

If you guys are on Windows and trying to access a local FTP on the same Wifi, you can put the ftp:// + address in the windows explorer address bar now that it is not even available in chrome flags in 2023.  I assume some of you will stumble on this when trying to use the feature within android file managers that have this option.